# How to move cell in tableViewCell with animation with usage of swipe action

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swipe

using: objective-C

I have a tableView with rows. I want that user can move cell a little aside and additional action shown to him.

What was done:

Currently create separately table in xib file and cell in xib file.
Cell is very simple
[image]

I want to move `viewWIthLabel`.
In cell class file for using animation I use next code

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * leftGestrudeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft:)];
leftGestrudeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer * rightGestrudeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight:)];
rightGestrudeRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self addGestureRecognizer:rightGestrudeRecognizer];
[self addGestureRecognizer:leftGestrudeRecognizer];
}
```

and actions:

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"swipeL");
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
    self.viewWIthLabel.frame = CGRectMake(-100, 0, self.viewWIthLabel.frame.size.width, self.viewWIthLabel.frame.size.height);
} ];
}

 - (IBAction)swipeRight:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"swipeR");
[UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
    self.viewWIthLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.viewWIthLabel.frame.size.width, self.viewWIthLabel.frame.size.height);
}];
}
```

So idea to swipe the cell and move it with animation for some distance to show a hidden button.

Result of this code - almoust like I want:

[image][image]

But if you start to scroll the tableView you can get duplicates of "swiped cells" in random (depending on scrolling speed) positions:

[image]

Any idea why it happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to clear/reset the swiped state of the cell in `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Since the cells get re-used (I am assuming you are doing that as would be required for good performance of the `tableview`). Probably something like this -

```
 self.viewWIthLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.viewWIthLabel.frame.size.width, self.viewWIthLabel.frame.size.height);
```

Comment: I try like you tell, but in this case, when you scroll sown, and than back, all cells reset their lets say "state", mean if you swipe it, scroll down and than back - you must to swipe it again. Are it's possible to save currently swapped cells?

Comment: You will have to code for that by setting a state (BOOL maybe indicating whether swipe menu is being shown or not) in a property in the data elements in the array constituting your `tableview` data.

Comment: Yes, at least this will ensure that re-used cells are restored to the "normal" position, then based on your state variable (like a BOOL) for that row, you can shift the frame again.

Comment: found also this topic http://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views VERY usefull